# How to handle JSON data from XMLHttpRequest POST, using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Overarching goal is to save some JSON data I create on a webpage to my files locally. I am definitely sending something to the server, but not in format I seem to able to access.

JsonData looks like:

```js
{MetaData: {Stock: "UTX", Analysis: "LinearTrend2"}
Projections: [2018-10-12: 127.62, 2018-10-11: 126.36000000000001, 2018-10-10: 132.17, 2018-10-09: 140.12, 2018-10-08: 137.73000000000002, …]}
```

XMLHttpRequest on my webpage:

```js
function UpdateBackTestJSON(JsonUpdate){ //JsonUpdate being the JSON object from above
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('POST', 'UpdateBackTestJSON');
 request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
 // request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");

 request.onload = function() {
   console.log("Updated JSON File");
 };
 console.log("about to send request");
 console.log(JsonUpdate);
 request.send(JSON.stringify(JsonUpdate));
}
```

and I handle posts on my server (rather carelessly I realize, just going for functionality as a start here)

```js
var http = require('http')
  , fs   = require('fs')
  , url  = require('url')
  , port = 8008;

var server = http.createServer (function (req, res) {
  var uri = url.parse(req.url)
  var qs = require('querystring');
  if (req.method == 'POST'){
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data){
      body += data;
      // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
      if (body.length > 1e6){ 
        // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
        req.connection.destroy();
      }
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
      var POST = qs.parse(body);
      console.log(POST); // PARSED POST IS NOT THE RIGHT FORMAT... or something, idk whats going on

      UpdateBackTestData(POST);
    });
  }
  
  function UpdateBackTestData(TheJsonData){
  console.log("UpdateBackTestData");
  console.log(TheJsonData);
  JsonUpdate = JSON.parse(TheJsonData);
  console.log(JsonUpdate["MetaData"]);

  //var Stock = JsonUpdate["MetaData"]["Stock"];


  // var Analysis = JsonUpdate["MetaData"]["Analysis"];
  fs.writeFile("/public/BackTestData/"+Analysis+"/"+Stock+".json", TheJsonData, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("updated BackTest JSON!!!");
  });
}
```

Most confusing to me is that when I run this, the Json object Im am trying to pass, does go through to the server, but the entirety of the data is a string used as a key for a blank value in an object. when I parse the body of the POST, I get: `{'{MetaData:{'Stock':'UTX','Analysis:'LinearTrend2'},'Projections':[...]}': ''}`. So my data is there... but not in a practical format.

I would prefer not to use express or other server tools, as I have a fair amount of other services set up in my server that I don't want to go back and change if I can avoid it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show **exactly** what `var POST` is (and what `body` is) - because it looks like you hav an object whose **key** is the JSON you are looking for (except it's not valid JSON as it is using `'` instead of `"`) - I'd say that `body` is the JSON you want to send to `UpdateBackTestData` - but I'm not sure (no idea what querystring.parse is doing to your body)

Comment: looking at when my server trying to parse my request data:
`req.on('end', function () {
      var POST = qs.parse(body);
      console.log('XMLHttpRequest of method post recieved');
      console.log(body);
      console.log(POST);

      UpdateBackTestData(POST);
    });`
server log:
`XMLHttpRequest of method post recieved
{"MetaData":{"Stock":"UTX","Analysis":"LinearTrend2"},"Projections":[]}
{ '{"MetaData":{"Stock":"UTX","Analysis":"LinearTrend2"},"Projections":[]}': '' }`